# What steps/equipment is needed to control a fan?

Tags: smart-home

I currently have a standard home fan in my bedroom, it's controlled with one light switch (on/off switch) and two pulleys on the fan unit itself. One pulley for the fan and one pulley for the light.

What equipment can I use to integrate it into a home automation system? This is the first thing I will be automating, so I have no equipment to begin with.

Basic functionality would be the ability to control the light and fan through an app on my phone.

Extra features that would be nice to have:

1. Dim the lights on the fan
2. Cycle through fan speeds
3. Schedule the lights/fan based on time of day
4. Automate fan based on bedroom temperature

**Edit** Thanks for the feedback and questions. I found [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/simple-ways-automate-ceiling-fan/) which helped me answer my own question.

Answer: "You need a switch such as 'Z-Wave Smart Fan Control from GE' or 'Insteon Hub Pro Advanced Central Controller'. You'll also need to decide which protocol you want to use, such as Zigbee, Z-Wave, Apple HomeKit, etc."

Comment: Get a motor DC controller and start from there. Unless your fan is AC.
Besides there are plenty of books for arduino and raspberry pi with small projects for starting hands on electronics.

Comment: This seems borderline off topic to me. Its discussing the modification of hardware to permit electronic control, not discussing any aspect of the connectivity. Also it is very broad - asking 'design me this' generally fails on SE sites.

Comment: See this meta discussion: http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/questions/69/are-how-do-i-build-x-questions-on-topic

Comment: This is an interesting question, and I'll happily vote to reopen if you add some extra information about your current setup, and how specifically you'd like to achieve your tasks. If you're unsure about how to even get started, consider breaking this question into smaller, more focused chunks.

Comment: @BenceKaulics - generally control of A/C appliances or especially built in electrical fixtures is *not* (and *should not be*) accomplished by "hacking" but rather by replacing the simple mechanical switches with existing controllable switches marketed for that purpose and designed by people with some professional sense of the issues involved in making them safe.  When there's a role for "hacking" it is in replacing the control signals *to* those controllable switches with your own command source, not in making your own A/C power or motor switches.